# Can't install iOS app with XCode (no developer account)

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

I'm trying to build [Mini vMac](https://github.com/pgodwin/minivmac-iphone) just for my iPad. As I don't have a developer account, I created a false certificate, but I'm still unable to build it for the iPad or to archive it in an IPA, because I don't have a provisional certificate for that app (I have one of a TestFlight beta, but obviously it doesn't works). What should I do?

Computer: iMac 21'5'' Late 2009, OS X 10.7.4 Lion, XCode 4.3.2

iDevice: iPad 2 32 GB Wi-Fi, iOS 5.0.1 (with Absinthe jailbreak)

Comment: *What should I do?* Buy a developer license.

Answer (score 0):

You going to have to either buy a developer license or jailbreak your iPad. Those are really your only two options.

Comment: I have my iPad jailbroken, what can I do?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I don't jailbreak.